# Conenct to RabbitMQ using Apache NMS STOMP

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, nms, apache-nms

I’m trying to read and write messages into/from a Rabbit MQ (3.6.5) queue using the STOMP protocol.
I’m using Apache NMS Stomp (1.5.4) as client library.

When sending a message using NMS I get the following exception:
**Input string was not in a correct format.**

The reasons is that NMS expects the filed **message-id** to contain a number at a specific position.
This is the code from the NMS library:

```
public void SetValue( String messageKey )
{
    key = messageKey;

    // Parse off the sequenceId
    var p = messageKey.LastIndexOf( ":" );
    if ( p >= 0 )
    {
        ProducerSequenceId = Int64.Parse( messageKey.Substring( p + 1 ) );
        messageKey = messageKey.Substring( 0, p );
    }
    ProducerId = new ProducerId( messageKey );
}
```

The message-id field sent by the Rabbit MQ Broker has the following value: 
*"T_ID:fig-52033-636066062974737556-1:0:1:1@@session-lOnNy1WnMfOTxEEVQmLHgg@@1"*
NMS tries to convert *"1@@session-Bo6HXXTZFSh51Qy7X4wx9A@@1"* to an Int64.

This is my client code:

```
var connecturi = new Uri( "stomp:tcp://localhost:61613?transport.useInactivityMonitor=false&amp;trace=true" );

Console.WriteLine( "About to connect to " + connecturi );
IConnectionFactory factory = new NMSConnectionFactory( connecturi );

using ( var connection = factory.CreateConnection( "XXXX", "XXXX" ) )
    using ( var session = connection.CreateSession() )
    {
        connection.Start();

        var destination = SessionUtil.GetDestination( session, "queue://FOO.BAR" );
        Console.WriteLine( "Using destination: " + destination );

        // Create a consumer and producer
        using ( var consumer = session.CreateConsumer( destination ) )
            using ( var producer = session.CreateProducer( destination ) )
            {
                // Start the connection so that messages will be processed.
                producer.DeliveryMode = MsgDeliveryMode.Persistent;

                // Send a message
                var request = session.CreateTextMessage( "Hello World! FROM NMS" );

                producer.Send( request );

                // Consume a message
                var message = consumer.Receive() as ITextMessage;
                if ( message == null )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "No message received!" );
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( "Received message with ID:   " + message.NMSMessageId );
                    Console.WriteLine( "Received message with text: " + message.Text );
                }
            }
    }
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

- A way to configure NMS to handle the id differently?
- A way to tell Rabbit MQ to generate other message-ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
Apache NMS STOMP expects the message-id field to be in a specific format. They try to parse a specific part of the message-id into a Int64 variable. (Seems to be Apache MQ specific.)
They fixed this problem in **version 1.7.1**, which sadly is not officially released… looks like the project is not very active / dead.

Bugfix: [Apache JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQNET-492)

I replaced the nugget package with a build of the latest source. 
This fixed my problem.

The source can be found here: [SVN repo](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/activemq-dotnet/)